# How to get the desktop resolution in Mac via Python?

Tags: python, macos

Trying to write a python application that downloads images from an RSS feed, and makes a composite background. How do I get the current desktop resolution on Mac OS X (leopard?)

Comment: it's because you use windows features to do stuff instead of cross platform lib. You are locking yourself into a trap. For picture manipulation, use PIL.

Comment: Alan: check this out: http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/pythonandquartz.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Pyobjc something like this should work. Pyobjc comes with Leopard.

```
from AppKit import NSScreen
print(NSScreen.mainScreen().frame())
```

With that, you can also grab the width and height.

```
NSScreen.mainScreen().frame().size.width
NSScreen.mainScreen().frame().size.height
```

For example:

```
print("Current screen resolution: %dx%d" % (NSScreen.mainScreen().frame().size.width, NSScreen.mainScreen().frame().size.height))
```

Comment: Yeah, pyobjc is quite something. And it's on every mac since Leopard. And remember when actually using this a lot of mac users have more then one screen. So account for that when needed. See Apple's docs on NSScreen for more info.

Answer (score 8):

If you are doing this from a LaunchAgent script, you may need to drop down to CoreGraphics primitives rather than AppKit-level methods. Working on this today, my LaunchAgent-loaded script gets `None` back from `NSScreen.mainScreen()`, but works fine if I load it from a terminal in my session.

```
from Quartz import CGDisplayBounds
from Quartz import CGMainDisplayID

def screen_size():
    mainMonitor = CGDisplayBounds(CGMainDisplayID())
    return (mainMonitor.size.width, mainMonitor.size.height)
```

Comment: This worked for me, once Quartz was installed with `pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz`

Answer (score 2):

As usual, using features that are binded to an OS is a very bad idea. There are hundred of  portable libs in Python that give you access to that information. The first that comes to my mind is of course pygame :

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480), FULLSCREEN)
x, y = screen.get_size()
```

But I guess cocoa do just as good, and therefor wxpython or qt is your friend. I suppose on Windows you did something like this :

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
width = GetSystemMetrics [0]
height = GetSystemMetrics [1]
```

Sure it's easier, but won't work on Mac, Linux, BSD, Solaris, and probably nor very later windows version.

Comment: The pygame example was not useful to me because you are getting the resolution of the pygame screen, not your physical screen. I don't know pygame very well so let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Your code took my screen into low resolution game window without any ability to exit. I was forced to reboot my Mac! Your concept is correct - we need a portable code, but the solution is bad because pygame.init() is opening a game window which we don't need.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a hard time getting any of this to work so I looked around and put something together that seems to work. I am kinda new at coding so please excuse any errors. If you have any thoughts please comment.

```
results = str(subprocess.Popen(['system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0])
res = re.search('Resolution: \d* x \d*', results).group(0).split(' ')
width, height = res[1], res[3]
return width, height
```

Comment: This does not work for me, `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType` outputs the maximum resolution of my screen, not the current resolution.