# CGPostMouseEvent replacement on Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I've been using CGPostMouseEvent() for performing mouse clicks since mac os 10.4.

While working on my code and trying to make it 100% compatible with Snow Leopard, XCode spit a warning saying that CGPostMouseEvent() is deprecated.
While this doesn't scare me, I'd like to know what replaces CGPostMouseEvent().
This is how I use it:

```
CGPostMouseEvent(point,FALSE,1,TRUE);  // mouse down
CGPostMouseEvent(point,FALSE,1,FALSE); // mouse up
```

That's all.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`CGEventCreateMouseEvent` can be used with `CGEventPost` in a non-deprecated fashion.  The reference is [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateMouseEvent).

---

**Edit from OP:**

Something like this?

```
void PostMouseEvent(CGMouseButton button, CGEventType type, const CGPoint point)
{
    CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, type, point, button);
    CGEventSetType(theEvent, type);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
    CFRelease(theEvent);
}
```

Comment: something like this:


void PostMouseEvent(CGMouseButton button, CGEventType type, const CGPoint point) 
{
     CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, type, point, button);
     CGEventSetType(theEvent, type);
     CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
     CFRelease(theEvent);
 }