# Send mouse Click message

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How we can make mouse click event in a certain position without moving mouse(I mean that make computer think a position is clicked with mouse) with C++

Answer (score 5):

The `SendInput` function in windows API will get you started. Have a look at the following link for the definition of the method,its input parameters and return values : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx

You can follow the links in the page to know more about the structures and data-types used in the function.

Update : 
You can start with something like this

```
#include<Windows.h>
int main()
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type=INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dx=0;
    input.mi.dy=0;
    input.mi.dwFlags=(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE|MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN|MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP);
    input.mi.mouseData=0;
    input.mi.dwExtraInfo=NULL;
    input.mi.time=0;
    SendInput(1,&input,sizeof(INPUT));
    return 0;
}
```

This will automatically move your mouse to the top left corner of the screen and make a right-click. Now, if you mean to make a click somewhere on the screen without moving your mouse, I think that is not possible using SendInput(). You do not need to worry about moving the mouse as your program will do it by itself. That is what the 'MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE' flag tells the program to do. If you do not use the flag, then the click will take place at the current position of your mouse.

Comment: I used
PostMessage(hwnd,WM_LBUTTONDOWN,MK_LBUTTON,MAKELPARAM(p.x, p.y));
PostMessage(hwnd,WM_LBUTTONUP,MK_LBUTTON,MAKELPARAM(p.x, p.y));
but it clicks where the mouse is it doesn't click the position i told to click

Comment: the link you said about inputs i saw but i couldn't find how to say click at a special position

Comment: mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,813,731, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,813,731, 0, 0); it clicks where the mouse is it doesn't click (813,731)

Comment: @ZiDoM : `mouse_event()` method is deprecated. You should avoid using it. Did you follow the links to the INPUT structure and then the MOUSEINPUT structure ? I am afraid you will have to dig and do some reading on the page I posted link to. Try and you will succeed :)

Comment: postmessage handles 1 of the messages.  the position is used for the move message, the mouse down, then the mouse up.  Clicking at a specified point requires 3 messages.

Comment: no.  You cannot simply combine move, button down, and button up.   Which one should go first?  Split this into 3 input packets.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SendInput()` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) to emulate mouse clicks and keyboard strokes:

> The SendInput function inserts the events in the INPUT structures
>   serially into the keyboard or mouse input stream. These events are not
>   interspersed with other keyboard or mouse input events inserted either
>   by the user (with the keyboard or mouse) or by calls to keybd_event,
>   mouse_event, or other calls to SendInput.

You can also use `SendMessage()` or `PostMessage()` to send the button-press message, e.g.

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(mousePosX, mousePosY));
```

, but it is less reliable. Note that in this way you may also need to send `WM_LBUTTONUP` later, depending on the way you handle events in your application.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492529/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-movement) question, the accepted answer is pretty detailed.

Comment: Also note that sending the message directly is unreliable.

Comment: How should i tell the position with INPUT structures without moving the mouse

Comment: @ZiDoM, well, you probably know _where do you want to click_, don't you?

Comment: i know the position but i dont want to move mouse there for clicking

Comment: @Zidom, mouse movement and mouse clicks are independent.

Comment: @ZiDoM : You do not need to move the mouse to a point on the screen and then call SendInput() to perform the click. I guess you can estimate the co-ordinates of the point at which you want to perform the click. If you want to click at topmost left corner, then the co-ordinates are x=0,y=0. If your screen resolution is 1280x1024,for example, then for performing a click at the center of the screen, the co-ordinates will be x=1280/2,y=1024/2. You do not need to move your mouse to the center for performing this click. Calling SendInput() with the proper parameters does that for you automatically.

Comment: i know the co-ordinates and i can send input but i don't know how to send input in a certain position

Comment: you cannot.  You must get the mouse current position, move the mouse to the click location, click the mouse, move the mouse back to the original location.  And nobody is any wiser.

Comment: I have found `SendMessage()` to be quite reliable, the issue is you need to send the **hWnd** value, and therefore the command only goes to that specific window. Odds are the window you want to send to is not the main window, so finding the correct hWnd can be tricky. In any case, using `SendInput()` should be much simpler.