# SendInput - (mouse movement simulation)

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, mouse, sendinput

I've been trying to simulate a series of inputs into a process.
The only one I was unsuccessful in achieving is mouse movement.
I have found the closest bet online:

```
bool mouse_move(int x, int y)
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.mouseData = 0;
    input.mi.time = 0;
    input.mi.dx = x*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));//x being coord in pixels
    input.mi.dy = y*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));//y being coord in pixels
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;//MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE
    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
    return true;
}
```

I did not understand the struct as it was explained online.
The mouse keeps going to the bottom-right corner of the screen no matter what value I input (except 0 obviously).

It was possible through `SetCursorPos()` yes, but once I went into the process, that function just didn't work anymore. I need to simulate it as if the user is inputting the mouse movement and so far `SendInput()` worked. I just can't seem to figure out the positioning.

Comment: Should help and probably answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492529/how-to-simulate-a-mouse-movement

Comment: Hmm, start by getting rid of the GetSystemMetrics() calls and just using x and y directly.   And consider that you *really* meant to use MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE and not incremental moves.  the latter will send it very quickly into the lower-right corner if you never pass negative values for x and y.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to place cursor in absolute coordinates, you have to add more flags:

```
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Only an hint: the best way to handle this kind of formula:

```
x*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN))
```

is to use MulDiv:

```
MulDiv(x, 65536, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN))
```

The code gets clearer and easiest to maintain.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34173641)

Answer (score 1):

### How to Handle Multiple Monitors with an Offset Virtual Screen Origin

It is possible to have the top-left of the virtual screen NOT be (0,0). If your primary monitor isn't the left-most monitor, is one out of many situations that would case the origin to be in the middle of virtual screen. To handle this, your transformation to mouse coordinates that range from (0,0) to (0xFFFF, 0xFFFF) must include translation and scaling.

```
// Calculate x and y relative to the top-left corner of the virtual screen
LONG x_tl = x - GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
LONG y_tl = y - GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);

INPUT evtMouse{};
evtMouse.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
evtMouse.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
evtMouse.mi.dx = MulDiv(x_tl, 0xFFFF, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN) - 1);
evtMouse.mi.dy = MulDiv(y_tl, 0xFFFF, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN) - 1);
evtMouse.mi.time = 0;
evtMouse.mi.mouseData = 0;
evtMouse.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not the proper equation : dx = x*(65536/GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN))

The proper equation is Y = mX + b, you have Y = mX.

This ONLY works if your primary monitor is the leftmost, and highest vertically of all of your monitors.  Otherwise the Virtual Desktop starts at a negative #, not 0.  But you are passing 0 in for b.

Normalized inputs are from 0 - 0xffff, but the non normalized coords often go from (<= 0 - >= PrimarymonitorWidth.   So you are most likely 1 or more monitors to the right and or down.

When you add in the b, or the Y-Intercept you should get the proper location.