# High response time - programmatically move mouse using pyautogui

Tags: python, mouse, mouselistener, pyautogui

In a python script, the response time for `pyautogui.moveRel(b, a)` is currently .1 sec. Is that the intended time for this function? If so, is there any way I can shorten this response time using another technique in python, or other languages? My goal response time is about 0.01 sec, which is the 60HZ rate.

Answer (score 2):

The results @mertyildiran obtained are to be expected, since PyAutoGUI has a default 0.1 second pause between actions as a [failsafe](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#fail-safes).

To speed things up, you can set the pause to a lower value, or even zero, like so:

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for checking the response time in microseconds(0.01 seconds = 10000 microseconds):

```
import pyautogui
import datetime

for x in range(0, 9):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    pyautogui.moveRel(None, 50)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()

    elapsed_time = end - start

    print elapsed_time.microseconds
```

Output:

```
269017
112927
113071
113061
112761
112561
113115
112107
112448
```

That means yeah it's approximately 0.1 seconds with this library and Python. So my recommendation is go with a deeper level programming language like C++.

Stimulate mouse event with C++ in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7492837/2104879

Stimulate mouse event with C++ in Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8791599/2104879

Answer (score 0):

you can use _pause=False as a parameter to moveTo and moveRel and most other pyautogui functions to disable the pause and make the movement instant.

examples:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, _pause=False)
pyautogui.moveRel(x, y, _pause=False)
mouseDown(_pause=False)
```