# Mac 10.6 cursor control in Python?

Tags: python, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Controlling the mouse from Python in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281133/controlling-the-mouse-from-python-in-os-x)

I'm trying to control the system cursor position on Mac OS X 10.6 with Python. Can I do this directly, and if so how? Or would I have to use something like PyObjC?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd need to use PyObjC, or write a shell utility to do the heavy lifting and `os.system` it. Check out this link, found with a 1 minute google search: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/bangpypers/2011-January/005572.html

Comment: What librarys are you using (if any), some can move the mouse. For example Pygame has `pygame.mouse.set_pos`.