# Moving the cursor in Mac OS X (in Python and/or R)

Tags: python, macos, r

Can someone please help me figure out how I can use a Python or R script to move the cursor in Mac OS X? The plan is to read a real time signal and based on the streamed value move the cursor up or down. Thanks for your help ...
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281133/controlling-the-mouse-from-python-in-os-x (You can the answer there)

Comment: I would like to see if someone has a solution for R

Comment: You could use the C code in the 'possible duplicate' and run that from R. Not a Mac person though, so don't ask me technicalities of compiling C on a Mac and linking R with Mac OS system libraries...

Comment: @RSK I voted to close because this question is a duplicate.  However, I too think the R answer would be interesting.  I suggest you clean up the question slightly (removing the Python references as you have a Python answer) to avoid this question being closed.  Note I also upvoted the question as I would enjoy seeing an R solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, R allows you to use C so it smells like cheating, but works:

```
library(inline)
move.cursor <- cfunction(c(x="numeric",y="numeric"),
  "CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPointMake(asReal(x),asReal(y)));
   return R_NilValue;",
  "#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>",,"C",
  libargs="-framework AppKit")
```

then you move the cursor simply by calling `move.cursor`:

```
move.cursor(100, 100)
```

Comment: Simon, I need to create spacebar press events using the same approach. Do you have any solution for that? I tried some codes, but couldn't get it working ...

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379867/simulating-key-press-events-in-mac-os-x shows the C code necessary - you just don't need `CGEventSetFlags` and you'll need to find the code for spacebar. I didn't have time to test it, though...

Comment: Simon,
I wrote the R version of that code and it works fine, however, I can't find CGKeyCode for spacebar and arrow keys. Is there anyway I can have a list of them and find them out?

Comment: Done! For number keys:

which.key <- 1
eval(parse(text = paste("c.key <- 'CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)", which.key+17, ", true); CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, e); CFRelease(e); return R_NilValue;'", sep = "")))
KeyPress <- cfunction(body = c.key,
                      includes = "#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>",
                      language = "C",
                      libargs = "-framework AppKit")
KeyPress()

Answer (score 0):

Also, in case someone wants to do the keyboard events, this is how it's done.
Below is the codes for typing numbers:

```
which.key <- 1
eval(parse(text = paste("c.key <- 'CGEventRef e = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)", which.key+17, ", true); CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, e); CFRelease(e); return R_NilValue;'", sep = "")))

KeyPress <- cfunction(
    body = c.key,
    includes = "#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>",
    language = "C",
    libargs = "-framework AppKit")

KeyPress()
```

Comment: You copied Simon's answer but forgot to include the library call?  Come on... at least go all the way.