# How to pause a Python script in the middle and resume it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

What I'm trying to do is a GUI program. I want a button that will pause the script where it is, and when I hit the button again, It will resume.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577467/pause-in-python) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366218/python-event-loop-multithreading-how-to-run-two-bits-of-code-simultaneousl).

Problem is, they are both dealing with the console, and the recomendations for those appear to be looking for keypresses, which isn't what I want to achieve.

Is there some way to just kind of freeze the script where it is, and then start it back up like nothing ever happened?

Comment: "pause the script where it is", is this in some sort of loop?

Comment: WeaselFox's answer below is what you want, unless you are trying to walk the program (or something more intimate), in which case you should probably hook into the python debugger (`pydb`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could freeze the process - (like `ctrl+z` in linux) and restart it whenever :

```
>>> import psutil
>>> somepid = 999
>>> p = psutil.Process(somepid)
>>> p.suspend()
>>> p.resume()
```

Comment: Does this work if the process is the python program? Like if I'm calling it recursively?

Answer (score 0):

OK, you are not giving much information, but I adapted a similar answer that I gave in other post, because I think it could give you the solution.
the example is with Threads, because is the first thing that came to my mind to do what you want. One Thread (func_control) takes care of the input and the other (func_1) does the real job.

The idea is that when you press Enter the function doing the job will pause or resume. It is important to have the `sleep(0.1)` in order to not overload the CPU. I have not included anything to finish the execution, but I think you can do that alone...  ;-)
Enjoy!

```
from threading import Thread

def func_control():
    global switch
    switch = 1
    while True:
        if switch:
            print "I'm doing stuff. Press Enter to pause me!"
        else:
            print "I'm doing nothing. Press Enter to resume!"

        if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
            line = raw_input()
            switch = 0 if switch == 1 else 1

def func_1():
    while True:
        if switch != 0:
            # Put all you need to do here!
            pass
        else:
            sleep(0.1)
    return 0

switch = 1

myThread1 = Thread(target=func_1)
myThread1.daemon = True

myThread1.start()

func_control()
```