# Python non-blocking input to communicate through serial with an Arduino

Tags: python

I have connected my Arduino to the USB and I want to read data from it, but also to send commands through serial.

The problem is that it prints  to the terminal what the Arduino sends, but not until I send command from the PC. I searched over other posts, and this happens because the input is blocking. I have read many posts on stackoverflow, such as this: [link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/python-nonblocking-console-input)

but everything I tried from there, does not work. I found this post: [link_2](http://ballingt.com/nonblocking-stdin-in-python-3/)

but I have problem with termios, and as I searched it does not cooperate with windows. Is there any way to make the code work without blocking and waiting from the input to write something? I started learning python programming python a few weeks, so maybe I missing something from code.

Comment: What issue did you have using the msvcrt module?

Comment: Does the mscvrt module work on its own if you remove all the Arduino code?

Comment: I execute this code: import msvcrt

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        print("you pressed",msvcrt.getch(),"so now i will quit")
        ser.write("you pressed",msvcrt.getch(),"so now i will quit")  but I don't see any reaction to the arduino nor to the python shell....

Comment: I use this code: import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        ch = msvcrt.getch()
        if ch in '\x00\xe0':  # arrow or function key prefix?
            ch = msvcrt.getch()  # second call returns the scan code
        if ch == 'q':
           print("Q was pressed")
        elif ch == 'x':
           sys.exit()
        else:
           print("Key Pressed:", ch)   from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365473/python-windows-msvcrt-getch-only-detects-every-3rd-keypress in python 3.5 but it does not work.Does it need any extra commands for python 3.5?

Comment: Replace the `set.write` with `print` to see if it comes in the python terminal