# program interrupt to perform logic

Tags: python

I want to be able to press any key to perform some sort of logic while other code is running. I don't know if parallel programming is required. I don't think it has to be. Basically I want to be able to perform something along the lines of this type of functionality

ex:

```
Welcome to questionnaire test (press 'j' to quit):

what is your fav color? # input answer
what is your fav number?
where are you from?
how do you do this?
press 'j'
#LOGIC
```

Pretty much I would be able to press a certain key at any moment to perform some sort of logic

I'm not sure where to look or how to implement this in python.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pygame`](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/about) you can check for input every time around the main game loop:

```
while True:
    elapsed = clock.tick(FRAMERATE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_j:
                # your logic goes here
```

This will check for input many times a second, so will seem instant to the user.

Comment: no that was merely and example. I want something like this. imagine youre playing a game and you press start to pause. Youre able to do so at anytime. I want to be able to do something like this

Comment: or maybe your logic is what i need but i am just not sure how to implement it

Comment: ex: if 'j' is ever pressed anywhere while running the program, do logic

Comment: hmm would u know of something else that doesn't require pygame?

Comment: What do you want, the moon on a stick?

Comment: something in teh standard library?

Comment: As I see it, you have two broad choices: some main loop you can keep checking in (like I've posted) or something ~parallel that can interrupt. I am not aware of any built-in "j pressed" module.

Comment: I think I might have foudn something. It seems as if pygame is the easiest way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207678/whats-the-simplest-way-of-detecting-keyboard-input-in-python-from-the-terminal