# How to add reaction to arrow keys in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add a reaction to arrow key. While I was trying to, I deciced to try just print the reaction when the key is pressed, as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38729688/9145780). When I write anything to console terminal, nothing happens. I am using PyCharm. 
Q: How to make it print the value as it should print?

```
 import msvcrt
 while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
       key = msvcrt.getch()
       print(key)
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I add what is recommend and what I used

Comment: this doesn't run because of indentation. What is the actual error you are getting? Are you on windows? Why is that linked answer the one you are trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** : Under run configuration enable this - Emulate terminal in output console (see below)

[image]

Remove extra indentation

### Error I get

File "run.py", line 2
    while True:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Code should be indented like this. Tested and it works.

```
import msvcrt
while True:
  if msvcrt.kbhit():
      key = msvcrt.getch()
      print(key)
```

[image]

Comment: The indetation isn't the problem, problem is, that the terminal do nothing if I press arrow key. I expected any output like the value of the key.

Comment: So the only way how to make it print the value is to use powerShell? Or is there any way how to make it in Pycharm?

Comment: Reading that this a problem with Pycharm. Still doing research.

Comment: Downloaded Pycharm and tested it. See updated answer for fix.

Comment: And you just run this script and press arrow keys in terminal?

Comment: Correct. My screenshot shows me pressing h key but it works for arrow keys and other keys.