# Detect which key-press

Tags: python

Related to [detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

We can detect any ASCII character key press from the answers there but is there any way to detect keys like '<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd>, function keys(<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>..) etc.

Preferably for windows.

Comment: Please enter your code, your attempts, and a bit more description.

Comment: I tried all the codes in the answers from the link, I do not know what else to try, they don't detect the keys mentioned. Do I put all those codes here? @Alex_P

Comment: Do you receive an error message?

Comment: No, nothing happens. No detection.

Comment: Did you try using `pynput`? You say preferably Windows and there are some comments on that thread which point to `msvcrt` a Windows-only module and he goes onto say **I actually use pynput now.** Pynput ref: https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

Comment: @WaynePhipps, `msvcrt` does not detect those keys. `pynput` is working(wasn't before for some reason). Is there a similar library for other OS?

Comment: `pynput` supports multiple os's

Comment: @WaynePhipps, it requires root right?

Answer (score 0):

For detecting `ctrl` or  `alt` or any function key like `f5` `f6` , you have to make your own function.

This code will print witch key you press so you come to know the string for a special. key.

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()
        print(key_stroke)   # will print which key is pressed
```

For Example, this code is for detection `F6` keypress

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()
        c1 = "b\'\\x00\'"
        c2 = "b\'@\'"
        if str(key_stroke) == str(c1):
            key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()
            if str(key_stroke) == str(c2):
                print('yes')
```

I hope it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest cross platform solution is [sshkeyboard](https://github.com/ollipal/sshkeyboard). It handles parsing the `msvcrt` output into readable characters.

Install with `pip install sshkeyboard`,

then write script such as:

```py
from sshkeyboard import listen_keyboard

def press(key):
    print(f"'{key}' pressed")

def release(key):
    print(f"'{key}' released")

listen_keyboard(
    on_press=press,
    on_release=release,
)
```

And it will print:

```
'a' pressed
'a' released
```

When `A` key is pressed. `ESC` key ends the listening by default.