# why does subprocess launch an "extra" application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I wrote a Python script to detect a `Print Screen` keypress, and launch the Snipping Tool. The script uses subprocess.call to handle the application launch.

The problem I am facing is that when I am done with Snipping Tool and close the application, I get an "extra" application being launched. For example, if I took a snip of a PowerPoint presentation, then when I close Snipping Tool I get a new / blank instance of Power Point being launched automatically. I do not want this to happen, and just want the Snipping Tool to close without any additional action.

Can someone please help explain what I am missing in my code?

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python
# https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/
# https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api

import keyboard #pip install keyboard
import time
import subprocess

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('print screen'):
        subprocess.call(r'SnippingTool.exe') # blocking; waits until open
        keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+N')
    #elif keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+print screen'): # not recognizing "print screen" here
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+esc'):        
        print 'killing it now'
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Do you have an updated code sample of the working solution?

Comment: @VictorS - I literally just commented out line 12 `keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+N')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing (and I'm not on Windows), but I think that the `subprocess.call` waits until you have finished with Snipping Tool, and so the `keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+N')` is going to PowerPoint.

Comment: Simple at that! I feel kind of dumb now, but a silly mistake is usually the best-case answer.