# How to exit loop on a keypress with python/osx?

Tags: python, opencv

I am on OSX.
I am importing opencv-python, so it might help; however, I am not showing anything, it's all command line off-screen processing.

```
While True:
   do work .... 
   key = cv2.waitKey(1)
   print key
```

The call to `cv2.waitKey(1)` consistently returns -1.
If I call `cv2.imshow(..)` before it, then it behaves correctly.

However, I have nothing to show, any chance I can still detect a keypress?

I need a keypress which isn't `ctrl+c`

Comment: Can you use the `ncurses` or `keyboard` Python modules? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python

Comment: @snibbets I couldn't get any of keyboard, ncurses to work on OSX. 'keyboard' just kept crashing.