# How to measure in Python the time lapse between keystrokes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a python program that measures trill velocity of pianists. Trills are a musical ornament consisting of a rapid alternation between two adjacent keys on the piano, so I think this can be simulated with two keys of the pc keyboard, like "K" and "O". Keys would be pressed at a frequency of 10 beats per second or higher.

Is there a way to register in Python the time when a keystroke happens?

Once obtained that data, I could use it to make statistics, etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python for detecting key presses, then record the current time when a keypress is detected.

Comment: Apart from the question being too broad, computer keyboards behave quite differently than piano keys, so the results would probably not be very meaningful.

Comment: It's true that they are different key types, but there is a correlation between the speed with which you trill on both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying keyboard library's pressed_keys example, as follows, I have achieved what I was attempting. However, for some reason, times are printed twice on the screen for each keystroke. Why does this happen? How could it be fixed?

```
"""
Prints the scan code of all currently pressed keys.
Updates on every keyboard event.
"""
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import keyboard
import time
def print_pressed_keys(e):
    #line = ', '.join(str(code) for code in keyboard._pressed_events)
    # '\r' and end='' overwrites the previous line.
    # ' '*40 prints 40 spaces at the end to ensure the previous line is cleared.
    #print('\r' + line + ' '*40, end='')
    a=time.clock()
    print(a)

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the time class. Depending on how much precision do you need, but you could do:

```
times = []

key_stroke:
    times.append(time.time()) #time.clock() for more precision
```

For the key detection method, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python) link. 
Also if you need to include more information on each key or distinguish between key presses, create a class and add one field with the time and other with the key.