# How to work around integer input within a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code is meant to run forever except for when `index_input == "Q"`. My problem is because i convert to an integer on the next line, the code fails and recognises the 'Q' as an integer.

```
while True:
  index_input = input("Enter index to insert element to list (enter Q to quit): ")
  index_input_int = int(index_input)

  if (index_input == "Q"):
    print('Good bye!')

    break

  elif (index_input_int >= 6):
    print('Index is too high')

  elif (index_input_int <= -1Q):
    print('Index is too low')
```

Expected result is that 'Q' will break the while loop.

Comment: Check for `Q` first and _then_ convert. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to convert the `Q` character or any other string to integer it will throw a `ValueError`. You can use `try-except`:

```
while True:
    index_input = input("Enter index to insert element to list (enter Q to quit): ")

    try:
        index_input_int = int(index_input)
    except ValueError:
        if index_input == "Q":
            print('Good bye!')
            break

    if index_input_int >= 6:
        print('Index is too high')
    elif index_input_int <= -1:
        print('Index is too low')
```

Comment: ValueError can also occur on the input line if the user just press enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the cast to int after the check for "Q" and put everything else in an else block:

```
while True:
  index_input = input(
      "Enter index to insert element to list (enter Q to quit): ")

  if (index_input == "Q"):
    print('Good bye!')
    break

  else:

    index_input_int = int(index_input)
    if (index_input_int >= 6):
        print('Index is too high')

    elif (index_input_int <= -1Q):
        print('Index is too low')
```

Comment: BTW, This may be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python