# How can I make a Python program run continuously from the Terminal (until I stop it manually)?

Tags: python

I have a python program which takes an input (a single character, 'y' or 'n') from the user and then executes a certain task based on that input. My need is to allow this program to run continuously from the terminal until I decide to stop it. Currently, I have to keep going back to the terminal and execute the program from there (and always type in that single character).

***PS:*** If it helps: the program adds data to a `MySQL` database, so I need this in order to make the whole process automated (and thus a bit quicker)

***EDIT***

My `my-program.py` looks like this:

```
main():
    if input().lower()=='y':
        #does something here
    else:
        #does something else
```

My requirement was to run a Python program infinitely from the Terminal. I do know how to use loops and how to perform tasks based on user input. What I wanted was to *automatically* give 'n' as the input character input whenever prompted.

`my-program.py` performs a certain operation when a character is given as input. When i call `my-program.main()` from another Python program using a while loop as below, I want to keep passing the same input (say `'n'`) whenever prompted (when the `input()` statement of `my-program.py` is executed)

```
import my-program
while True:
    my-program.main()
```

Comment: Write another script that executes your program in a loop.

Comment: Notice how `subprocess.comunicate()` lets you pass input to plumb through to the subprocess as an argument. Thus, inside a `while True` loop you could potentially do something like `p = subprocess.Popen(['myscript', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE); p.communicate('n')` to run `myscript` repeatedly, giving it `n` on its input. (Mind, you probably should have some kind of a delay on this script so it isn't just an indefinitely resource-consuming busy loop).

Answer (score -1):

First install **keyboard** package:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

Then write the code:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
while True:  # making a loop
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break  # if user pressed a key other than the given key the loop will break
```

Soruce: [Keyboard input detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to accept input (and even then, the `keyboard` library is best suited to special cases where stdin or the regular TTY interface don't work, and I see no reason to believe this question reflects one of those special cases); they're asking how to _provide_ input to a separate program.

Answer (score -1):

General case: the 'yes' command, it would use 'y' as your default option and won't ask you over and over again.

$man yes

yes - output a string repeatedly until killed [...]

DESCRIPTION:
Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.
It is probably equivalent to --force-yes and thus dangerous. If you still want to do it, you pipe the output of yes:

```
yes | <command>
```

Comment: This is tagged and posed as a Python question, not a UNIX question.