# Adding reading some character in while loop

Tags: python

I am reading serial data in while loop, I want to add something in code that if I press t than something should be print otherwise while loop should work. I tried to use readchar, but it wait for me to press some key, I dont want it to wait. I want while loop to work till I press some key

Raspberry pi 2.7

```py
while True:
    data = s.recv(xxx)
    print(data)

    if (x == t)
        print(Hello)
    else:
        continue
```

it is waiting if i use read char.

Comment: Not valid python.  Fix the grammar and indentation first.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of questions already asked on similar topics which would solve your problem. Some of them include the following:

[Loubo's "detect key press in python" here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python), as well as Spae's ["Python key press, detect (in terminal, no enter or pause)"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394609).

You could use:

```py
import keyboard as kb
num = 0
while True:
    if kb.is_pressed('t'):
        num += 1
    print (num)
```

Besides that, you have grammar and indentation errors.
Please consult this post on the [SO Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so further problems like this do not occur.

Comment: Hello Maxxy, Thanks alot for your help, I have added this code in my program but now I am getting error (you must be root to use this library on linux)