# (Python with msvcrt) how to detect keyboard input from another active window?

Tags: python, keyboard-events, msvcrt

I have the following script, which detects keyboard inputs and prints the pressed keys:

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key = msvcrt.getch()
        print("Key is {}".format(key))
```

The problem is that I can only type/enter characters into my terminal window, where the script output is. In other words, if I open a new program/window and start typing there, the script is not detecting the input. How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a keylogger type of functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just want to have a pipeline from a game to python, where I can save my keyboard inputs that I press inside a game. Also the reverse - being able to send inputs to the game using Python.

Comment: See if this helps. [detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

Comment: Thank you, seems to work exactly as I want it.