# how to terminate python script using while loop and get the result?

Tags: python, random, time, while-loop

i would like to generate random numbers for 5 minutes. after that, i would like to know the most common numbers.

my question is:

I am not sure about how much time I need. Can i MANUALLY terminate the script at 1 minute or 1 minute 19 seconds and get the result

my code is as follows:

```
import random
from collections import Counter
t_end = time.time() + 60*5
numbers = []
while time.time() < t_end:
    number=''.join(map(str, [random.randint(0,9)for value in range(0,4)]))
    numbers.append(number)

print(Counter(numbers))
```

Comment: why do you want to use a time period and not a range of iterations?

Comment: Are you trying to demonstrate `randint`'s distribution is uniform?

Comment: Quite a convoluted way to test the distriubution. `numbers` grows around 150k items/s. This is close to 50mio items for 5min. Tried counting with a regular dictionary? And is the weird random-expression on purpose? Using just `randint(0,9999)` is 4 times faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a myriad number of options:

- print an intermediate result every 5s or so and abort the script with ctrl+C
- check if space or something else is pressed, if so, abort the loop (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44754161/1311571) for how to)
- listen to [signals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) and handle accordingly (this could also gracefully terminate the script for option 1)
- open a socket and listen to a socket if a stop signal comes in
- create a gui with TKinter or what and add a stop button
- ...

The first one is the easiest but also the most quick&dirty one. For the second option, the following script should get you started (your script was working for me after adding whitespaces and linebreaks):

```
import keyboard
while True: 
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p": 
        print("You pressed p") 
        break
```

Assuming python3 and windows: Note that `keyboard` is not shipped with python on default. You need to install it with `pip3 install keyboard`. `Pip3.exe` might not be on your path. cd to where you installed python and look around. For me it was in the Scripts-folder (my installation is pretty messed up though).

Comment: mind to tell me the first method? can you illustrate it? i pressed ctrl+c but could not have any result.

Comment: if possible can tell me the second method? i used the following code  but I could not get the result as well                                                                                  import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        print("You pressed p")
        break

Comment: @pythonbeginner Updated answer, your script was working for me after adding linebreaks. Did you install the package? For the right python-installation? For the first: I run the scripts directly in console. If you use an IDE there thould  be a stop button or something somewhere to abort the currently running script (ctrl+C does not do much more on console).

Comment: hi, i run the scripts in console, yes, the method 1 works

Comment: for method 2, i have failed to get the result. this is my code:                                                                         
import random
import keyboard
from collections import Counter
import time
t_end = time.time() + 60*5
numbers = []
while time.time() < t_end:
    number=''.join(map(str, [random.randint(0,9)for value in range(0,4)]))
    numbers.append(number)
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p": 
        print("You pressed p") 
        break
    else:
        continue
print(Counter(numbers))

Comment: i download the code in .py format. after that i run the code on command prompt. then i type pyton abc.py. after a while i press ctrl+C, i have keyboard interrupt and cannot get any result.

Comment: @pythonbeginner see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python (second answer looks easier to set up)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random
from collections import Counter
import time
t_end = time.time() + 60*5
numbers = []
while time.time() < t_end:
    number=''.join(map(str, [random.randint(0,9)for value in range(0,4)]))
    numbers.append(number)
    if time.time()==(t_end-60*4): # break a 1 min
        break
print(Counter(numbers))
```

Comment: hi, can i MANUALLY terminate the script at 1 minute or 1 minute 19 seconds and get the result

Comment: are you sure that the break condition will work fine? (time.time() returns floating point numbers)

Comment: It works just fine, I tried it and it stopped exactly at 1 min span

Comment: pythonbeginner, the code I wrote above stops automatically at 1 min, if you want to break MANUALLY, press Ctrl+C

Comment: hi 5x shanks, i pressed ctrl+C, i could not get any result. i am not sure about the time. can i  terminate the script and get the result at 49 seconds or 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

As luigigi already mentioned in the comment, you could simply use the number of iterations as a limit, and use a for-loop:

```
number_of_iterations = 10000

for i in range(number_of_iterations):
    place_your_function_here()
```

However, if you for some reason really want to use the time, here is how you can do it: Update the current time at the bottom of your while block, and in the continuing condition of the while loop, compare it to the finish time:

```
import datetime


delta_in_seconds = 60
finish = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(0, delta_in_seconds)
while time < finish:
    place_your_function_here()
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: can i MANUALLY terminate the script at 1 minute or 1 minute 19 seconds and get the result