# Python Code that returns true while key is pressed down false if release?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I need a code in python that returns an if statement to be true if a key is pressed and held down and false if it is released. I would like this code to be able to be executed whenever the key is pressed and held down.

Comment: show your code and what you found in Google.

Comment: Seems similar/identical  to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python
More details on keyboard can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: when you press key then you can set variable `pressed = True`, when you release key then you can set  `pressed = False` and between both methods you can check `pressed` to see if you still keep pressed key.

Comment: @furas I am new to python so can you explain how this would look built out?

Comment: what module do you use for key presse ? PyGame, pyglet, pynput, other ?

Comment: @furas I am thinking of using pynput. Lets say I want create a while loop that will continue to print a letter until I release it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some systems keyboard can repeate sending key event when it is pressed so with `pynput` you would need only  this (for key 'a')

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode

def get_pressed(event):
    #print('pressed:', event)
    if event == KeyCode.from_char('a'):
        print("hold pressed: a")

with Listener(on_press=get_pressed) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

But sometimes repeating doesn't work or it need long time to repeate key and they you can use global variable for key to keep True/False

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
import time

# --- functions ---

def get_pressed(event):
    global key_a # inform function to use external/global variable instead of local one

    if event == KeyCode.from_char('a'):
        key_a = True

def get_released(event):
    global key_a

    if event == KeyCode.from_char('a'):
        key_a = False

# --- main --

key_a = False  # default value at start 

listener = Listener(on_press=get_pressed, on_release=get_released)
listener.start() # start thread with listener

while True:

    if key_a:
        print('hold pressed: a')

    time.sleep(.1)  # slow down loop to use less CPU

listener.stop() # stop thread with listener
listener.join() # wait till thread ends work
```