# How to make a stopwatch that will begin with the press of a certain button (a), and then stop after pressing a certain button (z)

Tags: python

I am simply trying to create a program where you type stuff as fast as you can. So, in this example, the goal is to have somebody type the alphabet as fast as they can. I just don't know how you would keep time whilst having them type specific characters. Thanks.

example: https://www.speedtypingonline.com/games/type-the-alphabet.php

Comment: Record the time they start, and subtract the current time from that when they're done to get the time elapsed.

Comment: Did you check this question out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python
It has the same kinda question

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].