# Play Sound whenever key is pressed in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, winsound

I am writing a Python script wherein everytime a key is pressed, a sound is played. 
I am using the Winsound module to play the sound, and I want something like this:

```
import winsound

while True:
    if any_key_is_being_pressed: # Replace this with an actual if statement.
        winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

# rest of the script goes here...
```

However, I don't want the "While True" block pausing the script when it is being run. 
I want it to run in the background and let the script carry on being executed, if this is even possible in Python.

Perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree and don't need a while true; if there is any way to play sound when *any* keyboard key is pressed, then please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python). I think it might be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pynput.keyboard module,

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import winsound

def on_press(key):
    winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly, but it pauses the script, so it doesn't run anything after it. Is there a way for the listener to keep running but not pause the script?

Comment: Yes, works perfectly! But what about when you hold a key down!? It repeats the sound in loop while holding the key down! Is there a way to stop that from happening? I mean, play the sound once until the key is released.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to execute on any keypress then the following code will work perfectly

```py
import msvcrt, winsound

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():   #Checks if any key is pressed
         winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

If you want to execute your code on a certain keypress then this code will work well

```py
import keyboard  
""" using module keyboard please install before using this module 
    pip install keyboard
"""
while True:  
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):  # if key 'a' is pressed 
             winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
            break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        break
```