# Is there a way to add sound effects to code python

Tags: python, audio

[new to stack overflow, don't know how to format. :) ]Trying to make it so when a user inputs something, it plays a sound, something maybe in this format?:

```
response = input(">>> ")

if response == 0
    #play sound?
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve but here is a similar issue and solution. On every button press on the keyboard a sound is played. Play Sound whenever key is pressed in Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172159/play-sound-whenever-key-is-pressed-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `playsound` module to play a sound file like `.wav` or `.mp3` (You need to have a sound file downloaded).

Install `playsound` using cmd with - `pip install playsound`.
[More info to install package](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/python-package-installation-on-windows/)

After installation, try this basic code to play sound -

```
from playsound import playsound

response = input(">>> ")
if int(response) == '0':
    playsound('path to sound file')
    print('Playing sound')
```

This would play the sound file when you type 0 as input

Check this for more info - https://pypi.org/project/playsound/

Comment: Is there a way to make the sound just play in the background from the beginning, kind of like background music?