# How to use '+' as input

Tags: python, calculator

I've just started to learn python. I'm trying to make a calculator as an intro project. For addition I've written:

```
if operation == "Addition":
    print("The answer is: " +str(num1+num2))
```

Later on the program asks what operation you want to perform. Instead of typing Addition I'd like to instead press the + key on my keyboard. Can I do this? I imagine the + key has some sort of code that I need to find?

Comment: If you read input from the keyboard into a variable, the code for the plus sign is, well, '+' :)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python

Comment: @Shijith, that’s not valid syntax. `any` returns whether at least one of the values in an iterable is true. Maybe you meant something like `if operation in [“Addition”,”+”]:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
op = input('please input the operation sign')
num1 = input('Enter first number')
num2 = input('Enter second number')

if (op == '+'):
    print("The answer is: " + str(int(num1) + int(num2)))
else:
    quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer I know is this: put all the possible options in a list and check if the user input is present in that list:

```
options = ['Addition', 'addition', 'add', '+', 'sum', 'Sum']

if operation in options:
    print("The answer is: " +str(num1+num2))
```

The advantage is that you can include any possible combination that the user could enter

Answer (score 1):

Check out [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

```
import operator

#tons of other math functions there...
di_op = {"+" : operator.add, "add" : operator.add}


num1 = 1
num2 = 2
operation = "+"


print(di_op[operation](num1,num2))
```

### output:

```
3
```

I.e. lookup the function in the dict - square brackets, then call the function you found using parenthesis and your nums.

for the prompt, this ought to do it, as long you press Enter.

```
operation = input("whatcha wanna do?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python) from stackoverflow about detected key input in python with [`keyboard.is_pressed()`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `win32api`

```
import win32api
import win32con
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_F3, 0) # this will press F3 key
```

Answer (score 0):

PyGame has those type of keypress features. Use a library such as pygame which will do what you want. Pygame contains more advanced keypress handling than is normally available with Python's standard libraries.

Here is the documentation:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/

here are the .key docs:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html