# In a python recursive input, how can I add functionality to the Up-Arrow to produce the content of the most recent input?

Tags: python

I have a sort-of 'hacked' CLI I'm trying to build. I have a global input in a while loop, and the user can perpetually enter 'commands' to produce various results. I'm wondering, how can I let the user press the Up-Arrow (as you would in a basic terminal) to put the contents of the latest entered command? The code will improve context.

```
while True:
    arg = input("(user) ~ ")
    if arg == "joke":
        print("There's a band called 1023MB. They haven't had any gigs yet.")
    elif arg == "hi":
        print("Hello.")
    
    # If arg == up-arrow: getLatestCommand()
    # I'm not quite sure how to implement this...
```

Example scenario:

```
(user) ~ joke
There's a band called 1023MB. They haven't had any gigs yet.
(user) ~ UP-ARROW PRESS
(user) ~ joke
```

I attempted to use the keyboard module in Python, but I was unable to get rid of this ugly thing: whenever I press the up arrow on mac in a Python input, it forces output of the following, "^[[A" which is annoying.

Comment: You will need to save the commands entered by the user and bind up arrow to a function which recalls commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for you input, however, I attempted that route, but I was unable to get rid of this ugly thing: whenever I press the up arrow on mac in a python input, it forces output of the following, "^[[A" which is annoying.

Comment: For one "up-arrow" command you can use a global variable but for more than one command you should use a list as a stack and for each command perform pop operation on that list.