# Key Press To Print Words (For Python)

Tags: python

Im lookting to see if its possible to print text with the press of a button, For example

```
Print("Text Here") if Press (key)
```

Im using this to make the introduction to my program more interactive. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using the OS module.

**Windows:**

```
import os
os.system('pause>nul')
print("Hello")
```

**Bash, (Linux):**

```
import os
os.system('read -n1 -r -p Press any key to continue')
print("Hi")
```