# How can I make a timer where I press the space button or whatever key on the keyboard to stop the timer?

Tags: python, timer

This is my Code:

```
seconds = 0
minuts = 0
while seconds > -1:
    rounded = round(seconds,2) 
    print(minuts,  'minutes,', rounded, 'seconds')
        
    seconds += 0.01
    time.sleep(0.01) 
    
    if rounded ==  59:
        s=0
        minuts+= 1
```

I want to press some key to stop the timer.

Comment: If you're on windows: https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit

Comment: No, I am on Macbook 2020 MacOS

Comment: It might be possible with curses, although I've never tried it.

Comment: Never heard of that but will try

Comment: Not sure if this would work but could you use multiple threads? One thread for the timer and another for a key listener that sets a variable to stop the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to make this work using the `keyboard` module in Python3 ([detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python))

This program simply loops the timer while the `space` key is not pressed, and stops when it is.

```py
import keyboard
import time

seconds = 0
minutes = 0

while not keyboard.is_pressed(" "):
    rounded = round(seconds, 2) 
    print(minutes,  'minutes,', rounded, 'seconds')

    seconds += 0.01
    time.sleep(0.01) 

    if rounded == 59:
        s = 0
        minutes += 1
```

If you need the `keyboard` module, use `pip install keyboard` from the command line to install it.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'. I did pip3 install keyboard. It still not working

Comment: So I did pip3 install keyboard 1 more time and it's saying Requirement already satisfied(Which I believe, it means it's already downloaded). And when I go to my IDE(Vscode). It's saying No module named keyboard

Comment: Did you use the vs code terminal panel? Just looking at this link (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) and wondered if that makes a difference?

Comment: I used it on the terminal and the Vscode 'sTerminal. It still showing the same. I even restarted my computer and still had the same issue

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could be then -- I tried it on my computer (PC) and it worked to install a new package and use it. This is probably a silly question but have you made sure to spell it correctly? For me intellisense does not show an error even if it is spelt incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, I have spelled the import keyboard correctly and said pip3 install keyboard. I copied pasted your code above and It's still saying that. I mean, I don't know if it is a glitch or not...

Comment: That is very strange. Have you tried changing the environment? In VS Code it is in the bottom left corner where it says ```Python <version> <32 or 64>-bit```. Maybe changing that will fix the issue. I have it on my actual python installation: i.e. ```c:\python38\python.exe```

Comment: Yes, I am running on Python 64-bit 3.7.6. I use Anaconda as my python installer. I also have python 64 bit 3.5.4 but it's still saying the same thing. I even created a Virtual Enviornment (Venv)but nope. This is really weird

Comment: Something strange has happen. I created a Venv with python 2.7.4 I am having no error and the I can't seem to stop the timer. I don't know if it is my fault or the python 2.7.4 and when I switch back to Python 3.7, it's showing that module error

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what would cause that to happen. Maybe it is worth posting another question?