# having a problem with conditioning selenium

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, conditional-statements

There is a problem (the "if" part).

It doesn't wait for me to click left arrow (as an example) to do the task and just instantly runs it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
if Keys.ARROW_LEFT:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gLFyf')
    element.send_keys('khkh')
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: You can refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

statement `if Keys.ARROW_LEFT:` will always be true

you have to use waiters. 
either `implicitly_wait` or `WebDriverWait`

so it will be

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gLFyf')
element.send_keys('khkh')
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

or

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gLFyf")))
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gLFyf')
element.send_keys('khkh')
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

helpful links: [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), [expected_conditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)

Comment: yes but i want to assign a key to activate the script