# How to do something till an input is detected in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

I want to execute a piece of code till the user enters an input(detects a **random** keypress), how do I do that in Python 3.x?

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
while input == False:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Hi, what is x? Which kind of input you expect from the user? Number, string, just key-press?

Comment: @CarloZanocco just keypress, x is just an arbitrary value

Comment: Ok, just handle it with KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: @CarloZanocco Keyboard interrupt is strictly `ctrl+c`, right?

Comment: does this answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python

Comment: @PlutonianFairy right. Answer updated.

Comment: @CarloZanocco That's what I was looking for, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
try:
    while True:
        print("Running")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("User pressed CTRL+c. Program terminated.")
```

The user just need to press Control+c.

Python provide the built-in exception [KeyboardInterrupt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) to handle this.

To do it with any random key-press with [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html)

```
import threading
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.user_press = False

    def RandomPress(self, key):
        self.user_press = True

    def MainProgram(self):
        while self.user_press == False:
            print("Running")
        print("Key pressed, program stop.")

    def Run(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.MainProgram)
        t1.start()

        # Collect events until released
        with Listener(on_press=self.RandomPress) as listener:
            listener.join()

MyClass().Run()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with users, you may follow the below way:

```
flag = input("please enter yes or no?")
if flag == "no":
    print(x)
```