# How to reset input from keyboard after delay?

Tags: python, input

Simple "input" in python:

```
code = input("Entrer your code...")
processCode(code)
```

I need to ask the user for a password on a usb keyboard but without a screen (so the user doesn't see what he is typing). The text here is just for some tests. The sending is validated by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key of course.

To make sure that the input is always blank when the user starts typing and sends his code, I will need to add a condition to this input.
I would need some sort of time counter which starts after each character entered and if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is not pressed for 10 seconds, the input will be automatically reset.

Comment: The answers given here may help you : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

Comment: @Tobin  keyboard library apparently requires root in linux

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code that approximates your question. You can improve it or take inspiration from it:

```
import keyboard
import time
from threading import Thread

start_time = time.time()
saved_pwd = False
stop_thread = False


def dedupe(items):
    seen = set()
    for item in items:
        if item not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(item)


def count_time():
    global saved_pwd, start_time
    while True:
        lap_time = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
        global stop_thread
        if lap_time >= 10:
            print("Please Re-enter the password")
            saved_pwd = True
            break
        elif stop_thread:
            break


password = []
Thread(target=count_time).start()
while saved_pwd is False:
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    start_time = time.time()
    if key == 'enter':
        saved_pwd = True
        stop_thread = True
    else:
        password.append(key)

print("Your pwd: ", ''.join(dedupe(password)))
```

Comment: Is there any suggestion without using the 'keyboard' library?