# Break when function run herself by console key pressing in separate thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, keyboard-shortcuts

For example:

```
def main():
    time.sleep(10)
    pass
    main()
```

How to break this loop by pressing 'q'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect key press in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python)

Comment: @Aggragoth not the same case. All solutions by link for while/for loops. Im my case need to break function.

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question or do you actually intend to recursively call a function within itself? Checking if a key is pressed as @Aggragoth suggested will work, you just need to put the if statement somewhere before the `main()` call. In saying that, you will probably run out of memory at some point too because you're recursively calling the same function which would fill up the call stack at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but i think this should work.

```
global stop
stop = False

def main():
    time.sleep(10)
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        global stop
        stop = True
        
    if stop:
        return 0
    else:
        main()
```