# How to Detect Keypress in Python

Tags: python

I am currently writing a program for a fake code/hacker typer which when in python and keys are pressed it prints out source code which makes the user looks like they are typing.

I know using the `keyboard` module you can use

```
import keyboard

keyboard.if_pressed(hotkey)
```

but how would one use this without specifying any key just if any key is pressed on the keyboard?

Comment: You could be talking about two different things.  If you're talking about grabbing keystrokes from the current terminal session, then the `msvcrt` answer will work on Windows, and there are ways to do it on Linux using "raw mode" input.  If you're talking about grabbing keystrokes systemwide, even when your app does not have focus, that a harder task that requires system hooks.

Comment: @TimRoberts I need something that will interact with the terminal regardless of the operating system used, but to clarify not something that would grab keystrokes systemwide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a single character from the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53210441/11915854

Answer (score 0):

```py
import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key_stroke = msvcrt.getch()
        if key_stroke:
            print("Clicked")
```

Comment: Only if he's using Windows.

Comment: This seems right but to clarify I was looking for something that would work on all operating systems.