# Python curses get keypress

Tags: python, curses

I need a way to detect both the arrow keys and the enter key. I don't have a numpad on my computer, so this statement is looking for a key that doesn't exist:

```
char = window.getch()
if char == curses.KEY_ENTER:
    stdscr.addstr("'enter' key pressed")
```

I would just use this to get the keypress:

```
char = window.getkey()
if char == "\n":
    stdscr.addstr("'enter' key pressed")
```

but I also have to get the arrow keys, with the `getch()` function. Is there any way I could use these two functions together, or another way that can get both keys that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at using the `keyboard` module, installed with `pip install keyboard`.

Something like the following could get you going, adapted from the modules [GitHub example:](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/examples/pressed_keys.py)

```
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    if e.event_type == "down":
        keys = [keyboard._pressed_events[name].name for name in keyboard._pressed_events]
        print(keys)
        if "up" in keys:
            print("do stuff for up pressed")
        elif "enter" in keys:
            print("do stuff for enter pressed")
    
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

[Black Thunder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8321664/black-thunder) gives a good detailed description of how to use the module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python).

Comment: No problem, glad i could help :).