# take count of how many times user pressed backspace key

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, backspace, python-keyboard

I am trying to take count of how many times the user pressed the backspace key while giving input. I am using the following code but it doesn't seem like working for me any help would be appreciated TIA.

```
word = input()
count = 0
for letter in word:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('\b'):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: pretty sure that `\b` gets applied in the terminal and only the final string is sent to `input()` - so not possible with `input()`

Comment: You probably want the `keyboard` module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44754161/10761353

Comment: Right -- `input` accumulates the input buffer until the user hits `ENTER`.  The method processes backspaces, so that the program never gets to see them.  You need to start over, handling `KEYPRESS` events.  Look up available packages to support individual keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect keypress event and construct the input yourself.
input give you final result, this does not contain the '\b'

https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-detect-keypress/

psedo code :

```
b_counter = 0
input = ''
while keypressed not 'Enter'
   if keypressed  is '\b' and len(input) > 0:
     input  == input [-1]
     b_counter += 1
   else:
      input = input + keypressed  

return input, b_counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Install module

```
pip install pynput
```

And try this code

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

global count
count = 0
def show(key):
    global count
    if(key == Key.backspace):
        count += 1
    if(key == Key.enter):
        return False

with Listener(on_press=show) as listener:
    listener.join()

word = input()
print(count)
```