# How to return to menu by a special key?

Tags: python, user-input

Is there any simple method to return to menu by entering a special key? If the user made a mistake while entering the input, user can return to main menu by pressing @ (a special key) key at the end of the input.

```
x = input("Enter first number: ")
```

Here, user enter 5, but want to exit by input @. So, x = 5@

I tried some including this

```
x=input("Enter first number: ")
print(int(a))
if x == "@":
exit()
```

Also tries this too

```
for x in ['0', '0$']:
    if '0$' in x:
        break
```

But, unable to handle numbers and string values together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses)

Comment: Not sure I got your question completely right, but you might want to try different approach: `if "@" in str(x): exit()`

Comment: Not sure what the final output needs to look like here. Can you show an example?

Comment: `if x.endswith('@'): continue`

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:
  x = input()
  if x[-1] == '@':
    continue
  # other stuff
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
user_input = input("Enter your favirote deal:")
last_ch = user_input[-1]
if(last_ch == "@"):
    continue
else:
    //Your Logic
```

Answer (score 0):

int(x) will not work if it contains characters other than numbers.
use this construction (@ will be ignored by converting a string to int)

```
x=input("Enter first number: ")
print(int(x if "@" not in x else x[:-1])) # minus last if has @
if "@" in x:
    exit() # or break or return, depends what you want
```