# I want to check if ANY key is pressed, is this possible?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, keyboard

How do I check if ANY key is pressed?

this is how I know to detect one key:

```py
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
while True:  # making a loop
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):  # if key 'q' is pressed
        print('You Pressed A Key!')
        break  # finishing the loop
```

How do I check if any key (not just letters) is pressed?
For example, if someone presses the spacebar it works, the same for numbers and function keys, etc.

Comment: `is_pressed('space') #-> for space
is_pressed('ctrl+space') #-> something else` check documentation for more info https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.is_pressed

Comment: I dont want it only for the spacebar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
while True:
    # Wait for the next event.
    event = keyboard.read_event()
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        print(event.name) # to check key name
```

Press any key and get the key name.

Answer (score 2):

it can be done using the `msvcrt` module as the following:

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key = msvcrt.getch()
        break
```

or the `keyboard`, although i am not sure of how of a **good practice** this code is:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    try:
        print(keyboard.read_key())
        break
    except:
        pass
```

if this is bad practice please informe me in the coments so i can mark it as **unfavored**

thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution in Windows is to use msvcrt
Please check thread here:
[How to detect key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses)

I think somehow should be possible also with builtin input() command.

Have a nice day!