# Detecting keypress while program is running

Tags: python

I have a program written in python and it could really use a script that can run at anytime during the main program running if a certain key is pressed.

If possible could this be done with a built-in so the user does not need to install modules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses)

Comment: If you only want to use the standard library, see the [library reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) to check if such function exists.