# Problem with keyboard.read_key() in Python

Tags: python

I want to capture the pressed key and do different tasks if it for example is `'1'` or `'2'`, etc.

This is my sample code:

```
import keyboard

key = keyboard.read_key()
if key == '1':
    print('something')
elif key == '2':
    print('something')
else:
    print('something')
    
str = input('Type something: ')
```

It works fine but for example when I press key '1', when the last line (input) runs, the output is like this (Terminal):

```
Type something: 1
```

Why Python automatically puts '1' at the end and how can I get rid of it?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `No module named 'keyboard'`. Which library do you use ?

Comment: Installed it through the 'pip install keyboard' command

Comment: Sorry. Too difficult to reproduce. Need to be root on Linux.

Comment: `keyboard` is intended to capture and send keyboard events going to *other programs*.  It doesn't actually consume the event, as that would make it useless for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could try swapping `keyboard.read_key()` for the `keyboard.is_pressed()` function to process the input, depending on the keys pressed

The post below might help more:

[How to detect key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses)

Comment: keyboard.is_pressed() waits just for a specific key, while the purpose is to execute different codes based on different inputs!