# I Want When Press any Key the Loop Finish in Python

Tags: python

I have a loop that make a Zigzag Shape and I Want to Stop this Loop when any Key Pressed

I want to stop the zigzag loop when I press any button from the keyboard (not a specific button like "Space" etc. Because I see many Articles that Use a specific Key I don't want that I want **any button from the keyboard**)

```
while True:
print("*****")
print(" *****")
print("  *****")
print("    *****")
print("     *****")
print("   *****")
print("  *****")
print(" *****")
print(" *****")
print("*****")
```

Comment: It seems that this is easy to do with the `keyboard` python package. Are you willing to use modules that don't come with the standard distribution?

Comment: Also, are you specifically looking to make this pattern in the standard out (i.e. with print statements), or would a tkinter gui be acceptable?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Can You till Me how to Use keyboard in this Example? and About Tkinter NO , I want to Use print Function BUT if this Example Can be Made with Tkinter SO can You Help Me ?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57644349/2476977). I believe something like `if keyboard.read_key(): break` should work, but I don't have the module myself to test this out.