# i want my turtle code start when user press enter key by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, turtle-graphics, pong

I want my pong game that is made by turtle module to start when user press Enter key (python)

what I did is just add s to start but I cannot do enter key he should type enter as string word not key

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! To get a good answer, pease improve for question. Maybe it is helpful to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking before asking ;)
Please add some code: what did you try so far, etc.

Comment: https://codeigo.com/python/check-if-user-pressed-enter this blog can help

Answer (score 0):

As @droebi mentioned, I would advise you to slightly improve the question, as there are some mistakes that add slight difficulty to read your question.

But from what I inferred, you want the user to not press the enter key, but actually type the word `enter` in the console to start the program.
This problem can be solved in two ways:

```
input("Type Enter to start:\n")
# your code
```

You can do this if you don't really care what the user is typing.

```
import sys
start = input("Type Enter to start:\n").lower()
if start == "enter":
  pass
else:
  sys.exit("You did not type Enter. Please type 'Enter' to start.")
# your code
```

You can do this if you want to be particular that the user **SHOULD** type `enter`.

In case you *did* want to start the program when the `enter` key is pressed, however, then you can take a look at the answers for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses)