# Is there a way to detect a key press in a python Replit?

Tags: python, user-input, keypress, replit

I am making a chat app in Replit through Python. I have a while true loop that checks if a message has been posted and will check if you pressed the T key, and if so, pauses the loop to let you type and send your message. Because it is on replit, I cannot give root access.

I have tried using the keyboards module functions, like `keyboard.is_pressed('t')`, but that requires root access. I have looked through the docs there and have not found anything. I have also tried using the solutions in [How to detect key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `getKey` Module for it:

```
from getkey import getkey
key = getkey()
if key == 't':
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Replit, but, if you're on a Windows machine, you might solve it with :

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    # Check if a message has been posted
    # ...

    # Check if the 't' key has been pressed
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        # Read the character from the keyboard
        ch = msvcrt.getch()
        if ch == b't':
            # Pause the loop and let the user type and send a message
            # ...
```

Not sure if it helps for your usecase, maybe for others. cheers.

Comment: Pip couldn't find msvcrt.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html

Comment: Oh replit is linux.

Comment: oh ok , I was not familiar with it indeed, apologies if it does not solve it for you. Unresolved indeed.