# Which Linux library should I use to call a method by pressing a key?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-22.04, msvcrt

i am trying to call a specific method by pressing a key for example: something like this:
`

```
import keyboard

list = ["a","b","c"]

while True:
    try:
        if key.is_pressed('i'):
            list.index("a")
        elif key.is_pressed('c'):
            list.count("a")
    except:
        print("Error!")
```

I tried msvcrt library and found out it was only available for windows(I am using linux ubuntu 22.04) I also tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses) and it did not work.

Comment: Did the script above work?  That's what `keyboard` was designed for.  However, how would you know whether it worked?  Your script is a 100% tight CPU loop that does nothing.  I think you forgot to use `print`.  Note that "did not work" is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [`readchar`](https://pypi.org/project/readchar/) library. It has some limitations but works for a lot of simple use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the well-known [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) library. Short example:

```
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()   # initialize curses

curses.halfdelay(1)         # wait 1 tenth of a second for keypress
t = 0
for ch in iter(stdscr.getch, ord('q')):
    if ch != curses.ERR:    # keypress
        print("You pressed %s in period %d"%(chr(ch), t))
    t += 1

curses.endwin()             # restore terminal
```