# How to detect any key pressed without blocking execution in Python

Tags: python

I have an script that checks the position of the mouse every 60 seconds. If the mouse has not moved, it moves it, makes a right click, clicks esc, and sleeps. It is pretty handy to avoid the computer going to sleep. If the mouse has moved, does nothing, goes to sleep and checks again in 60 sec.

Now I want to extend it to detect any key pressed. and take it in the same way as the mouse. If a key has been pressed, then just go to sleep.

I found the module keyboard, that allows to detect pressed keys. However, it blocks the execution while waiting for a pressed key. Therefore, I would like to find a way to stop "listening" with keyboard after an specified time. That way, instead of sleep, I would use that. If either the mouse is moved or the keyboard is pressed don't do anything.

I have not been able to find anything that works for Windows. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use method #3 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/57644349/9997212:

> **Method #3:**
> Using the function `on_press_key`:
>
> ```
> import keyboard
>
> keyboard.on_press_key("p", lambda _: print("You pressed p"))
> ```
>
> It needs a callback function. I used `_` because the keyboard function returns the keyboard event to that function.
>
> Once executed, it will run the function when the key is pressed. You can stop all hooks by running this line:
>
> ```
> keyboard.unhook_all()
> ```

This will allow your program to be event-oriented and will not block your main thread.

To listen to all keys instead of a specific one, use [`keyboard.hook`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardhookcallback-suppressfalse-on_removelambda). It works the same way:

```py
import keyboard

keyboard.hook(lambda event: print(f'You pressed {event.name}'))
```

The key is to set up a global variable as a boolean. The hook works as an interrumption, therefore, everytime that it is triggered, you activate as True the boolean. After the check that you need you turn it back to False. Something like this:

```py
import keyboard

try: #the try, finally is used to activate and relase the hooks to the keyboard
        
        def handle_key(event):
            global KeyPressed #the almighty global variable that monitors whether the keyboard was pressed or not.
            
            KeyPressed = True
            # print("KeyPressed is now:", event.name) #in case you want to know what did you pressed.
            return 
        
        global KeyPressed #the almighty global variable that monitors whether the keyboard was pressed or not.
        
        KeyPressed = False #initialize as False, no key was touched

        keyboard.hook(lambda event: handle_key(event) ) #this activates the detection of pressed keys. Must end with "keyboard.unhook_all()"

        if not KeyPressed: #means you have not pressed a key
            do_something()
                
        else: #Then a key was pressed
            KeyPressed = False #reset the pressed state to False
                    
        sleep(PAUSE) #wait the specified pause
finally:
        keyboard.unhook_all() #this resets the "keyboard.hook(lambda event: handle_key(event) )" so that no more keys are registered
```

Comment: Hi enzo. Your proposal works. But I honestly don't know how to use it. The keys are in fact detected and printed in the console, but I don't know how to access information within the keyboard.hook() function to use it in an if statement for instance

Comment: From my (admittedly brief) reading of the linked question and answers there, this one would seem like a duplicate. Why not vote to close instead of posting an answer that is mostly quoting an answer from there? (I'm just curious and don't want to cast a close vote without a better understanding)

Comment: @El_que_no_duda the `keyboard.hook` function takes one argument: a callable that itself receives an argument `event`. That can be a lambda, or it can be a function. If you define a function `def handle_key(event)` containing whatever you want it to do, you can do `keyboard.hook(handle_key)`

Comment: @pho I couldn't find any mention of `keyboard.hook` on that question, and at least I didn't saw any other answer that offered a proper way to listening *any* keypress without blocking using the `keyboard` module. So I thought to add my own answer to this question. I'm sorry if this is not a good practice here, and let me know if you want me to delete my answer.

Comment: @pho can you add a code snippet? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @enzo your answer is by far the most valuable thing I have found in the past 4 hours of trying to solve this problem

Comment: @enzo Ah, I see, I'd leave your answer up.

Comment: @El_que_no_duda code within a comment wouldn't be rendered nicely, but I'll try to explain what I meant: `keyboard.hook` takes one argument. You see the `lambda event: print(...)` in enzo's example? That is the one argument. It is a _callable_ (a lambda can be called), that takes _one argument_ (`event`). Internally, it prints `event.name`. A function defined using `def ...` is also a callable. So if you defined a function `def handle_key(event)`, you could put whatever you want inside it. Since the `event` argument is passed to this function, you could use the attributes of `event` to, ...

Comment: ... for example, check the [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.hook) for `keyboard.hook`, and it tells you that `event.name` is _"an Unicode representation of the character (e.g. "&") or description (e.g. "space")"_ so if you wanted to check if the key pressed was `x`, you could have `if event.name == 'x': <do what you want to do when the x key was pressed>` in the definition of the `handle_key` function

Comment: @pho I have now edited the answer from enzo with my interpretation of your comments. I think it goes in the direction of your suggestions

Comment: @El_que_no_duda I suppose, if that works for you, you can go for it! :) I think you forgot to add a `while True` loop before the `if not KeyPressed` line though, because the code you have there currently won't do anything because that `if not KeyPressed` line is run only once, and you most probably wouldn't have pressed a key in the time between the hook being set up and that line being run