# How can I detect if a key is pressed in the terminal?

Tags: python-3.x

Specifically, I am creating a Python 3.4 program that runs entirely in the terminal. Is there a cross platform way to detect if a specific key is down? I can do it on Windows using the `win32` function `getAsyncKeyState()`, but don't have a way to test keys on OSX or Linux.

I know about `getch()`, but that doesn't let me test for some keys (such as shift) and waits for key repetition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way of detecting keyboard input in python from the terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207678/whats-the-simplest-way-of-detecting-keyboard-input-in-python-from-the-terminal)

Answer (score -1):

If you start up a tkinter window and hide it bind keypresses?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Control-e>", exit)
root.mainloop()
root.withdraw()

while True:
    name = input("What's Your Name? ")
    print(name)
```

This will hide the window once it is made checking for Ctrl+E keypresses
and when it gets one
it exits the program.

Hope This Helps :)