# Press Enter to continue in Linux OS

Tags: python, debian

Environment is Beaglebone Black which is running Debian Linux and Python.

I need a function which will wait for only <kbd>Enter</kbd> hit and will return True. Anything apart from <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I don't want to show keypress in terminal (act like keyboard doesn't work). `raw_input` will show pressed key in terminal. I need something similar as `os.system("pause")` which works in Windows.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207678/whats-the-simplest-way-of-detecting-keyboard-input-in-python-from-the-terminal). Pres enter call some proccess from in a thread. What pause ? Ignore all keystroke is pause ?

Comment: If a user is prompted "press ENTER" he probably won't fool around pressing other keys ... So is that realy critical to not show "accidental" key presses ? Because avoiding `raw_input` seems like an awfull lot of complication ...

Comment: you are right, raw_input is much easier. wanted to look good