# How to measure time between next pressed keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keystroke

I am looking for idea how to measure time between next pressed keys in python. 
I know that I can use input/raw_input, but it is connected with pressed "enter - I want to catch any pressed key.

e.g. pressed A, next pressed B, time between A and B is 0.500 s

I would be grateful for your help. Thanks

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207678/whats-the-simplest-way-of-detecting-keyboard-input-in-python-from-the-terminal

Comment: Question Op was asking is for time lapse between key strokes. not for detecting the key,

Comment: I want to measure time between pressing, detecting the key is part of that what I want to reach.

Comment: Keystroke detection itself needs a third-party package and are platform-dependent; there are several options listed in the questions linked by others in these comments.  Once you've chosen how to do that, simply catch the moment of a keystroke using `datetime.datetime.now()`, then subtract the latest one from the previous one. You'll get a timedelta object which has various methods to give you the value you need, such as `my_td_object.total_seconds()`.