# Communication to the raspberry pi through SSH

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I want to talk to my raspberry pi 3 using SSH on an Android device. How can I make my python script listen on the commands sent through SSH ?

I use to be able to do that on my Arduino and would like to do the same on my PI can I do that ?

Comment: Welcom to SO ! Please supply your code.

Comment: I have no code done. I'm trying to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after countless hours looking through Python code and a bunch of trial and error. I finally found something that works for me. Here's the code I'm using on my raspberry pi to read the terminal :

```
import termios, fcntl, sys, os
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()

oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)

oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

try:
    while 1:
        try:
            c = sys.stdin.read(1)
            print "Got character", repr(c)
        except IOError: pass
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
```

So I start my python code from the Terminal using python3 myscript.py and what ever I input get's trapped.

Works like a charm. Hope I can help someone else with this.

Forgot to add the link to the answer I found : [What's the simplest way of detecting keyboard input in python from the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207678/whats-the-simplest-way-of-detecting-keyboard-input-in-python-from-the-terminal)