# detect key press in python, where each iteration can take more than a couple of seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redhat, keypress, amazon-linux

**Edit:** The below answer to use **keyboard.on_press(callback, suppress=False)** works fine in ubuntu without any issues.
But in **Redhat/Amazon linux**, it fails to work.

I have used the code snippet from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
while True:  # making a loop
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        break  # if user pressed a key other than the given key the loop will break
```

But the above code requires the each iteration to be executed in nano-seconds. It fails in the below case:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
import time
while True:  # making a loop
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        print("sleeping")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("slept")
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        print("#######")
        break  # if user pressed a key other than the given key the loop will break
```

Comment: Your program will detect nothing during the sleep call.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @James The above program is just a illustration. Problem is, key press is not detected if each iteration in while loop is taking more than a couple of seconds.

Comment: Check this examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/31736883/5274713

Comment: Did you try with another library? like evemu and python-evdev, keyboard had been inconsistent (for me at least)

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of event handlers in `keyboard` module to achieve the desired result.

One such handler is **`keyboard.on_press(callback, suppress=False)`**:
Which invokes a callback for every `key_down` event.
You can refer more at [keyboard docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardon_presscallback-suppressfalse)

Here is the code you can try:

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
import time

stop = False
def onkeypress(event):
    global stop
    if event.name == 'q':
        stop = True

# ---------> hook event handler
keyboard.on_press(onkeypress)
# --------->

while True:  # making a loop
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        print("sleeping")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("slept")
        if stop:  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        print("#######")
        break  # if user pressed a key other than the given key the loop will break
```

Comment: @NarenBabuR You have to run this program as a root user, as mentioned in the docs of keyboard.

Comment: before running the program, executing sudo su solves the problem

Comment: @NarenBabuR Yep, that will do.

Answer (score 2):

for people that might need this in the future, you can use `keyboard.wait()` which will basically wait untill the key gets pressed

```py
keyboard.wait("o")
print("you pressed the letter o")
```

Do keep in mind that it blocks code execution after it. if you want to run code if the key is not being pressed i'd suggest doing

```py
if keyboard.is_pressed("0"): 
    #do stuff
else: 
    #do other stuff
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `keyboard.wait()` to wait for ANY key event, either a key up or key down?

Comment: @will-hedges There is!, With `trigger_on_release=` if true, the callback is invoked on key release instead of key press.

In the case below it triggers when the key is released
`keyboard.wait("o", trigger_on_release=True)
print("you released the letter o")`

Answer (score -1):

Edit: never mind, the other answer uses pretty much the same approach

This is what i could come up with, using the same "keyboard" module, see in-code comments below

```
import keyboard, time
from queue import Queue 

# keyboard keypress callback
def on_keypress(e): 
    keys_queue.put(e.name)

# tell keyboard module to tell us about keypresses via callback
# this callback happens on a separate thread
keys_queue = Queue() 
keyboard.on_press(on_keypress)

try:
    # run the main loop until some key is in the queue
    while keys_queue.empty():  
        print("sleeping")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("slept")
    # check if its the right key
    if keys_queue.get()!='q':
        raise Exception("terminated by bad key")
    # still here? good, this means we've been stoped by the right key
    print("terminated by correct key")
except:
    # well, you can 
    print("#######")
finally:
    # stop receiving the callback at this point
    keyboard.unhook_all()
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use a thread

```
import threading

class KeyboardEvent(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop

keyread = KeyboardEvent()
keyread.start()
```

This would run in parallel to anything in the main thread and be dedicated to listening for that key press essentially.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, though, it would just check for the keypress once the thread was started, and then the thread would exit. Did you mean `while not keyboard.is_pressed` instead?