# Python: Detect what keyboard modifiers (ctrl, shift, alt) are pressed on startup of the script (Linux)

Tags: python

I would like to detect what modifiers are pressed on startup of my program. So far I haven't found any good libraries or methods for that. What I found are

- WxPython, Tkinter, PyGame, and the like, which can all get the modifier states, but need a GUI for that and I don't want to
- keyboard (https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/), which I didn't look further into because it needs root and I don't want to grant that
- pynput (https://pypi.org/project/pynput/). This comes the closest, however it cannot detect a pressed key or modifier on startup - as far as I see in the documentation, the only provided things are callbacks for keyup and keydown (https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard), however these are not called when the key is pressed on startup, as well as the Controllers.modifiers (https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Controller.modifiers), however these are not the actual state of the physical keyboard, but rather pynput internals (see this issue: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20).

I am looking for a way to *detect if modifiers are pressed, that works without root, without GUI, and at startup*.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Would this be of use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207678/whats-the-simplest-way-of-detecting-keyboard-input-in-python-from-the-terminal/13207724

Comment: Something like a keylogger, but with some changes to fit your situation better.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Basically all answers rely on termios for Unix, and that does not detect modifiers like CTRL, so that doesn't work

Comment: a pyxhook Keylogger also doesn't work, as it cannot detect keys pressed before the actual program started